# Drupal site moved from development to live - IE won't load stylesheets anymore

Tags: theming

Before you ask ... I have looked everywhere for a solution, even drupal.org but nothing so far seems to work.

I developed a Drupal site (custom child theme for Zen) and on the development server everything looks fine in all browsers.

I did a test migration to another server before the launch. This move went well and everything looks fine in all browsers.

Then I moved the site to its live server where everything looks fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer which is not loading the stylesheets.

I know Drupal is known for generating many stylesheets and Internet Explorer will not load them if there are more than 31 (I believe) of them, but I did set the "Aggregate and compress CSS files" feature and clear the cache. This did not seem to help.

Could the answer be in one of the two following things?

1. The development site and backup site are both with one hosting provider. The live site is with a different hosting provider.
2. The development site and backup site are in subfolders of two different portfolio sites ... ie www.portfoliosite.com/Newsite.
   The live site is a subdomain of the parent site ... ie www.newsite.parentsite.com.

I have run out of ideas so if anyone has a possible solution or direction to look, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: let us know the IE Version.

Comment: Maybe this will help:
"...Empty the cache from your localhost database.  The easiest way to do this is with phpMyAdmin, make sure to clear all the tables starting with ‘cache_’ or ‘<prefix>_cache_’ ). This step is very important as your site might not work properly or even worse when you export the SQL file it will be to large and will not upload properly."
Source: http://www.designshifts.com/how-to-move-a-drupal-website-from-localhost-to-a-live-server/

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking two things:

1. Is there a difference in settings for caching and/or CSS aggregation on live vs. dev?
2. Have you tried clearing the cache via the button in the UI? Doing it from drush does not clear the CSS caches, and it also has some other behavior that's different from the UI button way.